# "QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm Could not load source layer for INPUT:" error when applying QGIS processing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, file-geodatabase, point-in-polygon, point-creation

Sorry, I'm not 100% sure of what is the cause here, it seems like maybe the path to the file but that appears to be correct. I have a bunch of data from the USACE's e-hydro website I'm trying to execute a couple of tasks on and looking to automate.

Here's what my code is:

```py
import os
from qgis import processing

with open(r'C:\temp\file.txt', 'r') as f:
    names = f.readlines()

    for name in names:
        name = name.strip()
        print(name)
        processing.run("native:randompointsinpolygons", {'INPUT':f'C:/temp/Houston/{name}/{name}.gdb|layername=SurveyJob','POINTS_NUMBER':10000,'MIN_DISTANCE':50,'MIN_DISTANCE_GLOBAL':0,'MAX_TRIES_PER_POINT':10,'SEED':None,'INCLUDE_POLYGON_ATTRIBUTES':True,'OUTPUT':f'C:/temp/Houston/{name}.shp'})
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
exec(Path('C:/Users/matth/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpt_sn5eek').read_text()) CESWG_DIS_GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self. Locals)   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>   File "<string>", line 7, in <module>   File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)   File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 170, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm Could not load source layer for INPUT: C:/temp/Houston/CESWG_DIS_GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS/CESWG_DIS_GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS.gdb|layername=SurveyJob not found
```

I'm not sure but it seems like it's saying the path is bad but it looks ok.  I copied the command from the random points in the polygons tool to get myself started and this executes with no problems and the path looks the same to me:

```
processing.run("native:randompointsinpolygons", {'INPUT':'C:/temp/Houston/CESWG_DIS_GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS/GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS.gdb|layername=SurveyJob','POINTS_NUMBER':10000,'MIN_DISTANCE':50,'MIN_DISTANCE_GLOBAL':0,'MAX_TRIES_PER_POINT':10,'SEED':None,'INCLUDE_POLYGON_ATTRIBUTES':True,'OUTPUT':'C:/temp/Houston/CESWG_DIS_GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS.shp'})
```

Comment: Removed CESWG_DIS_ from my name list and added it before the variable.  Sorry I didn't notice...knew it would be something simple but not that.

Answer (score 1):

As @Taras said:

> Notice a difference between `CESWG_DIS_GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS` and
> `GA_03_OBC_20231107_CS`

I didn't realize there was a prefix in the folder `name` for the usage district that wasn't in the Geodatabase name. Modified the `name` in the file list text file and added the prefix before the variable in the command.